# CKAN/Solr: JSP support not configured

Tags: jsp, solr, ckan

I have problem following steps while installing CKAN on ubuntu 14.04 (elementary OS Freya 0.3)

Specifically this one:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#setup-solr

When I start JPS server and open http://localhost:8983/solr/ I have the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/index.jsp. Reason:

    JSP support not configured
Powered by Jetty://
```

Can you tell me what happen? Adding `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`
 to jetty config does not help.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jsp.html might help

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions here and it worked --

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2966

```
cd /tmp
wget https://launchpad.net/~vshn/+archive/ubuntu/solr/+files/solr-jetty-jsp-fix_1.0.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i solr-jetty-jsp-fix_1.0.2_all.deb
sudo service solr restart
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this bug report - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=740596 as mentioned in https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/2019 and https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/1651

Answer (score 0):

You must have Selected J2EE Preview at localhost server to run this program, so instead of that use apache tomcat server, if not defined then please manually select this server and run it.
It worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

@ashishsingal worked for me with a minor change to restart jetty instead of solr, i.e.:

```
sudo service jetty restart
```